# Compression for Spring remoting with JSON

Tags: json, spring, compression, remoting

I am trying to enable compression for json responses from server. Currently i see the response but not compressed, below i have mentioned the config.

Server: Jetty

---

### Servlet.xml

```
<bean name="/TaskSearchApp.json" class="com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="taskSearchAppBean"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.webmethods.caf.TaskSearchAppInterface"/>
</bean>
```

---

### Web.xml

```
     <filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

### Client-bean.xml

```
</bean>
    <bean id="taskSearchAppBeanJSON" class="com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://localhost:8888/TaskSearchApp/TaskSearchApp.json"></property>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.webmethods.caf.TaskSearchAppInterface"></property>
</bean>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Ok I could sort this out by adding
extraHttpHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");

But now i get the error while parsing the gzipped response

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.NoCloseInputStream@700a4488; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:532)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:478)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2508)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:617)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2926)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2873)